# For which measures does the monotone convergence theorem hold?

Tags: measure-theory

The standard proof of the monotone convergence theorem for the Lebesgue measure picks a simple function $\phi$ that is uniformly bounded above by the pointwise limit $f$ of the monotone increasing sequence of positive (Lebesgue) measurable functions $\{f_n \}$ in question; fixing a $k \in (0,1)$, sets of the form $E_n = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f_n(x) \geq k\phi(x)\}$ are claimed to be an increasing sequence of measurable sets that cover the entire space (the reals). (Sneaking in a quick question here: why do we use $k$ at all? Is it so that we can always 'squeeze in' elements in $E_n$ in case $\phi=f$?)

I think the claim that the sets are measurable relies on completeness of the Lebesgue measure; could someone confirm this? Can this proof be adapted to non-complete measures (say, the Borel measure)? For what kind of measures on the reals does the convergence theorem hold? Is there an analogue of the theorem for measures on other ordered fields possessing the least upper bound property?

Comment: Actually I do not recognize your description of the proof. Can you give a link to it? Have you taken a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Theorem_2) already?

Comment: You will find the exact description in the link in the proof section of the case with the Lebesgue integral -> 'proof of the theorem' -> independent proof (step 3).

Comment: Thank you. But nowhere I can find that it should only concern the Lebesgue measure (or a complete measure).

Comment: Right; I meant to seek confirmation on the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The monotone convergence theorem holds for any measure space: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem%23Beppo_Levi%27s_monotone_convergence_theorem_for_Lebesgue_integral)

The real numbers are (up to order isomorphism) the only ordered field with the least upper bound property (this property is called "*Dedekind completeness*") This is a well-known fact ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_field)) and there is a proof in an appendix of Spivak's  "*Calculus*".

*Sneak answer*: if you don't use in $k$ then the sets do not necessarily cover $\mathbb{R}$: let $g$ be the characteristic function of $[0,1]$. What if $f_n=(1-1/n)g$ and $\phi=g$? Also, the proof should not require completeness of the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra at any point.

Comment: If we disallow $\phi$ from being the limit of the $f_n$, i.e. $f$ (which is equivalent to demanding the existence of a simple function strictly less than $f$ so that for a sufficiently large $m$, $f_m \geq \phi$), then can we discard the use of $k$?

Comment: @SystematicDisintegration I assume you mean $\phi(x)<f(x)$ whenever $f(x)\neq 0$. In this case, yes, we don't need to use $k$. But there is a trade-off, since we would have to prove that the integral of $f$ is the supremum of the integrals of such $\phi$. This argument should actually be somewhat hidden in the proof of the monotone convergence, if it is the one I have in mind.